# What is the step for detect pendrive in Vmware Mac OsX Guest OS in Windows Host

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I have install mac on Windows-7 with the help of Vmware.But I had faced problem to show pendrive on virtually installed Mac..And also facing problem how to move files from windows to Virtually installed MAC.....I am using Vmware Workstation-8

Comment: Not really programming related. Voted to close and relocate.

Comment: @Abizern: Why? The FAQ says: if your question generally covers ... `software tools commonly used by programmers` ...

Comment: Most people take that to mean the IDE, frameworks etc. But this is more about setting up your computer. And regardless of it being about running Mac in a virtual environment - actually belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: @Abizern: I think you're wrong, because the post deals with a software tool. ;) Anyway, you've expressed an opinion.

Comment: @A_nto2 Yes I have. But I'm not the only one to have that opinion as you can see by the number of close votes. This isn't about slamming down the questioner. This question doesn't belong here - it belongs on the sister site where it will likely get more and better answers. As part of closing this question here it will automatically be moved to that site.

Comment: @Abizern: I have just complied with the FAQ. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Vmware Player, actually, but I suppose the procedure would be quite close. Try launching the virtual machine and than try something like:

> Virtual machine menu --> Removable devices --> (your usb device name)
>   connect

You really should install the `Vmware tools` to get rid of your issues.
Install these after you have started the vistual machine.

Comment: You are right When plug USB it indicates that connected but usb is not shown in Virtually installed MAC

Comment: I have idea that  I can share folder between Host and guest..But don't know how it is done?

Comment: Did you install VmWare Tools???If yes, jou can just do copy-paste from Windows to the Vmware Mac OS.

Comment: yes i had installed.

Comment: Let me know how it is possible I had installed VWware tool on MAC os but there is no option to copy and paste.

Comment: Go to the Windows desktop, choose a icon link, right click -> copy. Go to the Mac desktop, right click->paste.

Comment: I had done all things But not show paste option while moving on MAC..

Comment: Probably the paste option could be in the top menu, I don't remember exactly...anyway, the above procedure, in a Windows to Windows works for sure. Should be in a Windows to Mac, as well.

Comment: Try to drag something, instead of copy-paste.

Comment: Dragging is not possible also..

Comment: Otherwise, you can move files through local network.

Comment: YES local Network is good idea But how it is done?please let me know.

Comment: Otherwise, try a quick install of Vmware Player. Then, open your existing Mac VM with Vmware Player, and redo the above steps.

Comment: I'm not practice with Mac tools.

Comment: Give me link from that I downlaod Vmware Player

Comment: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=player. You must register before you can download. Anyway, it's all free of charge.

Comment: By the way, remember to install the Vmware tools from the vmware-workstation ones, if Player won't supply them. Bye! :)